# How to start vNext TFS 2015 build revision at a specific number

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, asp.net-core

I am using the vNext build system of TFS 2015.

I currently have the my builds versioning in the traditional format.  Major.Minor-rev.RevisionNumber.  So, if I have a build for Major 1, Minor 12, the build version would look like 1.12-rev.1 when I start.  I would like to know if it is possible to have the build version start at a number other than one, say 55.  Such that the build version would look like 1.12-rev.55, and then increment by one as usual after that.

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong, it is possible! See answer from @Steve Sims https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195443/1196586 and my comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/52332883/1196586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible.

Every build definition has a **build number format** field where you can use some macros to dictate what the resulting build number should look like. In this format we are using `$(Rev:.rr)` Its start by one.

> **What is $(Rev:.rr)?**
>
> To ensure that every completed build has a unique name. When a build
> is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev
> integer value is incremented by one.
>
> Source:[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190719(v=vs.120).aspx#rev)

Moreover, if you want to generating a custom build number without increment.
Here is a blog with detailed procedures:[Generate custom build numbers in TFS Build vNext](https://blog.ehn.nu/2015/10/generate-custom-build-numbers-in-tfs-build-vnext/)

Comment: It's impossible in on premise tfs or vsts?

Comment: @StingyJack  Unfortunately, neither for now.

Comment: Not being able to set the starting seed is what makes Release Management unusable for programs that had released versions before the feature was made available.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Link "Generate custom build numbers in TFS Build vNext" now stale.

Comment: @CJBS Thanks for the reminding, the OP changed the blog address. Have update the link, should work now.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT This is actually possible. I found the answer here on SO (cant find it now at the moment) but its just running a powershell script to get the current number and then change it however you need to (i had to bump it from 1 to ~3800 so the new build def would pickup where the old one left off.

Comment: Ha, the actual answer is below by Steve Sims. Maybe I should scroll down instead of googling for it.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is possible to effect this in a vNext build without hacking the database.

There are 2 steps.

First,  you will need to implement a powershell build step (as the first step of the build) with the following inline script:

```
#Set the BuildNumberOffset. (Change this to the difference between the TFS build number,
#and the number that your build needs.) 
$BuildNumberOffset = 543  

#Don't change 
$BuildNumberParts = $($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER) -split '\.' 
$TFSRevision = [int]$BuildNumberParts[$BuildNumberParts.Length-1] 
$BuildNumberParts[$BuildNumberParts.Length-1] = ($TFSRevision + $BuildNumberOffset).ToString() 
$BuildNumber = [string]::Join(".", $BuildNumberParts) 
Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$BuildNumber"
```

Second, on the Label format field of the repository tab set the label format to "$(Build.BuildNumber)" instead of "$(Build.DefinitionName)$(rev:.r)". This is important so that your label will be the same as your updated build number.

Comment: This does work! But the important point to note is that it does only work if you use an inline powershell script in your build!!! 
First I stored the script locally on the build computer which did not work...
Second important point is that the powershell script has to stay in the build script. If you remove it, the offset is gone. So the next build will not look for the highest number that was run before!

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this. It isn't pretty, but it works.

Assuming you have a build number format of something like `$(Major).$(Minor)-rev$(rev:.r)`

To do this queue up a build which will get the number 1.12-rev.1. Then go to the TFS database and into a table called `tbl_Build`. Find that last build you did and change the value in the `BuildNumberRevision` column to 54.

The next build that fires off will now be 1.12-rev.55

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't we just manually set this in the format for one build i.e:

```
$(Major).$(Minor)-rev$(rev:.54)
```

and then afterwards revert back to:

```
$(Major).$(Minor)-rev$(rev:.r)
```

Not tried it, but if it works it'll save hacking around in the database.

Comment: Almost worked - the build ran with the manually set number, but after reverting back to $(Major).$(Minor)-rev$(rev:.r) it continued from the original numbering not the manually set one.  Not sure why as surely the manual number was now in the database?  But didn't work in any case....

Comment: You may have a collision once it gets to that 54 again.

Comment: I tried, but when switching back to $(rev:.r) it started again with 1

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46195443/1196586) of @Steve Sims works still with **TFS 2017 vNext**. Thanks a lot!

I had only to do the first step "to add the script as an inline powershell script in my build." Thanks to @PainElemental

With this "Build number format" in the Options-Tab it works:

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_1.2.0$(rev:.r)
```

I didn't label my sources with the build, so I don't checked:

> Second, on the Label format field of the repository tab set the label
>   format to "$(Build.BuildNumber)" instead of
>   "$(Build.DefinitionName)$(rev:.r)". This is important so that your
>   label will be the same as your updated build number.

I think, you can edit the Label Format on the "Advanced" GetSources Options. (usually hidden).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily, but only if you are using a Git repository in conjunction with a tool called [GitVersion](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io)

It is a wonderful tool that I always use with my git repos.  For your use-case:  When you have version 1.2.3 and you want to jump to version 1.2.55, you just add a git tag 'v1.2.55' and it will start the versioning from there.  GitVersion is a lot more complicated and does a lot more, but that is one of the features.  You don't have to mess with special PowerShell scripts or anything, it instead reads your git repo history and git tags overrides the calculated versioning.  There is already a TFS/VSTS/Azure Devops extension called GitVersion that works great from the same developer.

Answer (score 0):

This was also very painful for us, migrating from a existing CI system with it's own build numbering, we needed build numbers to increment from a specific value.   Hacking databases wasn't allowed in the organisation, offsets seemed a cludge.

In the end, we used an AutoIt script to start and stop builds and delete the build result using the WebUI and left it running.   Not nice, but it did the job.

Needs tweaking for screen resolutions and such, timings also perhaps. Use AutoIt Window Info to find the button locations, make sure browser is fullscreen (not windowed)   Run it for a few cycles to ensure it robust before setting the loop larger.

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
;Increment TFS build count (Chrome browser buttons locations).  Start from build result page.

For $i = 1 To 15 Step 1

ConsoleWrite ( "Loop " & $i & " of 5" & @CRLF )
Sleep(200)
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_PRIMARY, 1800, 200, 2)
Sleep(500)
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_PRIMARY, 1150, 881, 2)
Sleep(2000)
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_PRIMARY, 1800, 200, 2)
Sleep(500)
MouseClick($MOUSE_CLICK_PRIMARY, 1055, 165, 2)
Sleep(10000)

Next
```

TFS/Devops is a really immature CI system, and it's not a patch on what we were running.  Unfortunately corporate policy said we move to TFS, as nobody ever got fired for buying Microsoft products (but plenty of people should have got fired for buying them/forcing them where they don't belong).