# Importing Sharepoint modules in TFS Powershell build script

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to run a release in TFS to Sharepoint Online and I can't seem to import and load the module.

I tried just a straight import-module statement:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -DisableNameChecking
```

I the found this solution but that's not playing ball either.

[How to load PowerShell Module from custom script on vNext build agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404652/how-to-load-powershell-module-from-custom-script-on-vnext-build-agent)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to load the assembly before you can use the types inside it.

You can use the loadfile method,

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile(“c:\folderwhereyouhavesharepointassemblies/thedllname.dll”)

Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
```