# VSTS Powershell Secret Variable

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

How can I use a secret variable in my powershell script in my release definition?

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404652/how-to-load-powershell-module-from-custom-script-on-vnext-build-agent) but it doesn't work. The directory `"$($env:AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY)\agent\worker\Modules"` doesn't exist on the new agents.

What's the correct way of accessing a secret variable on new hosts? My agent version is 2.114.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By [design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch#SecretVariables), you have to pass the value of secret variable through PowerShell parameters.

For example:

Variable: `password (secret)`

task: `PowerShell`

Arguments: `-pass $(password)`

Script:

```
Param(
 [String]$pass
)
if ($pass) { Write-Host "variable is NOT null" }
if (!$pass) { Write-Host "variable is null" }
```

Comment: Is there a way to access it inside the script -- not passing it as a param?

Comment: @Mardoxx No, you need to pass it as parameter. https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent/issues/145

Comment: NB: Should be a `[SecureString]` rather than `[string]`.  https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingPlainTextForPassword.md

Comment: @JohnLBevan No, the value will be decrypted in build task.

Comment: When using an inline PowerShell script, I get the error: `Param : The term 'Param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this now with-out the parameters, see my script below

[image]

```
Write-Host "Client Id " $env:client_id;

Write-Host "Client Secret" $(client_secret)

$applicationId = $env:client_id;
$clientsec = "$(client_secret)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $clientsec
```

Comment: You really need to have quotes around `$(client_secret)` when passing it as an argument to `ConvertTo-SecureString`. I was struggling with it for a long time. Adding quotes finally got it working.