# How to pass TFS 2018 password (Hidden) variable in a powershell script

Tags: tfs, passwords, environment-variables

I have a powershell script that I want to run as part of a release. The script will create a ServiceNow Change request. The script works fine if I embed the user and password on the script (stored as variables) and that was great for testing. Now I want to store the user name and password in TFS Variables.

I been successful in pulling in the TFS variables when they are stored a plain text. But when I "lock" the password in the variables (make it hidden) the the authentication fails to ServiceNow. I'm sure it has to do with the method that I am using, but I am not a true programmer, I just goggle code snips and piece it together. Here is a portion of the script:

```
$user = "tfs_changerequest"
$pass = "$env:SNPWD-Hidden"  # doesn't work with hidden password


# Show SN Password #
Write-Output "SN Password #" $pass                # This looks correct
Write-Output "SN PW Hidden #" $SNPWD-Hidden       # This appears to have worked

# Build auth header
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user, $pass)))

# Set proper headers
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Authorization',('Basic {0}' -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add('Accept','application/json')
$headers.Add('Content-Type','application/json')
```

Again this is just a snippet but the error I get is:

```
##[error]Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

I think it has something to with the $base64AuthInfo line I'm guessing the the password variable ($pass) has to be unhidden, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To use a secret variable in a powershell script, you could use this  `$secret = "$(MySecretVariablet)"` sample snippet:

```
....
$secret = "$(MySecretVariablet)" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $applicationId, $secret
```

If you're trying something like `Write-Host "$secret"`, I think it is intended to not work, to, well, keep it secret.

For more details, please take a look at below two links:

- [VSTS Powershell Secret Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43047116/vsts-powershell-secret-variable)
- [I can't pass secret variables to an inline powershell script
  task](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/8345)

Comment: To add a bit you can even save those credentials to an xml file on the build server in the agent APPDATA and then consume it.  You would do like this

Comment: I tried to simplify the script to just pulling the variables, If the password variable is not hidden then this works. If I lock the password in the variables. then it it returns empty. I even converted to an inline PS script in the release step.     
$user = "tfs_changerequest"
Write-Output "SNPassword 2: " $env:SNPassword # works in clear text
Write-Output "SNPassword 3: " $env:SNPASSWORD # works in clear text
$secret = $env:SNPASSWORD | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
Write-Output "secret: " $secret

Comment: @PatDelaney As mentioned in the reply, you could not use any format to Write-Output your secret variable. It is supported to be either empty or `*****` or system.security.string. It's a protected password value, we could not see it from plain text. But we could use this variable to authenticate through `$Credential` . I am afraid your method of authentication may require some plain text password, you could choose another way just I or Etienne mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a credential file like this.

First ask for credentials and save it to an xmlfile in the build userprofile, you would do this anytime the password changes.

```
$Credential = Get-Credential
$Credential | Export-CliXml -Path "${env:\userprofile}\mycreds.xml"
```

this will create a file that looks like this

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <ToString>System.Management.Automation.PSCredential</ToString>
    <Props>
    <S N="UserName">user</S>
    <SS N="Password">Encrypted string</SS>            
  </Props>
</Obj>
```

then you can consume it like this

```
$cred =  Import-CliXml -Path "${env:\userprofile}\mycreds.xml"
```

and use $cred in any -Credential parameter.

Note that this file is only valid on the computer you generated it on.  The encrypted string is for that machine only, so even if someone brings it to another machine it won't work.